# How to grant access on Azure Database for MySQL in the portal?

Tags: mysql, azure, azureportal, azure-mysql-database

How can I grant permissions on Azure Database for MySQL in the portal to other user? I don't see 'Access Control (AIM)' for it anywhere.

Comment: See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-data-access-and-security-vnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Database for MySQL is a fully managed database as a service in Azure. It is different from the SQL Database those will link a SQL server resource when you creating SQL database. For SQL Database, IAM is set at the server level, not at the individual database. Here is [a similar reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/766b99d3-64b1-4a78-9b16-6ade57893c16/azure-portal-why-i-dont-see-quotaccess-control-iamquot-within-sql-azure-management-options?forum=ssdsgetstarted) for SQL database.

For Azure Database for MySQL, It seems there is no IAM setting in the portal.
If you want to control access for Azure Database for MySQL, you can use firewall and SSL. You can see [Data access & security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules) in the [Azure Database for MySQL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/) for more information.